# Is PHP immune to "HTTP Response Splitting" vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, security, http-headers, exploit

```
<?php
setcookie('test', "test\r\n<script>alert(1)</script>");
echo 1;
```

But it turns out PHP automatically does the encoding:

```
Set-Cookie: test=test%0D%0A%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

Does that mean it's impossible to reproduce [HTTP response splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting) in PHP?

Comment: Even dated php versions filter all header and setcookie calls. And why don't you just output the script tag with echo instead?

Comment: @mario ,please go over the link I provided above.

Comment: So what about it? It doesn't explain the purpose of *your* question. Else the answer is simply: yes, not reproducible in current php versions. The wikipedia article devotes a whole paragraph on explaining exactly that.

Comment: @mario ,the whole thing of http response splitting is done in the **header**,while `echo` only outputs stuff in the **body**

Comment: So if you really need that capability, just downgrade to PHP 5.1.1 or before.

Comment: If might be possible by messing with the string encoding. (i.e. UTF-7 and UTF-8 mixing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting) Wikipedia article:

> [...] Although response splitting is not specific to PHP, the PHP interpreter contains protection against the attack since version 4.4.2 and 5.1.2. <sup>[[1]](http://php.net/changelog)</sup>

[`header`](http://php.net/header) and [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) contain mitigations against response/header splitting. It's not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the protection?

Comment: @mario how do you know setcookie is immune? I am not able to find any references on setcookie and response splitting

Comment: @charlieb Just forwards its constructions to header() basically: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/37cd86080f716e5187cae2f2547d7d5deedb9839/ext/standard/head.c#L79